# access AD recycle bin through LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Working with a Windows 2016 server, how do I query its recycle bin through
LDAP? The bin is active and, according to the AD admin center, currently
contains two OUs I removed yesterday. Through *wellKnownObjects*, AD gives the
bin location as `cn=Deleted Objects,dc=example,dc=com`.

However, when I query that DN for `objectClass=*`, neither entry is returned:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <CN=Deleted Objects,DC=example,DC=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectClass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 5
result: 32 No such object
matchedDN: CN=Deleted Objects,DC=example,DC=com
text: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100241, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best 
 match of:
    'CN=Deleted Objects,DC=example,DC=com'


# numResponses: 1
```

What’s does the server actually need?

Edit: Researching the issue a bit further, MS seems to have a
specific LDAP control [LDAP_SERVER_SHOW_DELETED_OID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366989(v=vs.85).aspx)
for exactly this use case. However I was not able to make deleted
objects show by adding `-e 1.2.840.113556.1.4.417` to the
*ldapsearch* invocation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that AD applies some sort of access control
to the recycling bin. Coming with an Admin ticket, it suddenly
works:

```
$ kinit Administrator@EXAMPLE.COM
$ ldapsearch -v -R EXAMPLE.COM \
    -H ldap://windowsbox.example.com:389 \
    -b 'CN=Deleted Objects,DC=example,DC=com' \
    -E '!1.2.840.113556.1.4.417' \
    -s sub \
    '(objectClass=*)' \
    distinguishedName

# Deleted Objects, example.com
dn: CN=Deleted Objects,DC=example,DC=com
distinguishedName: CN=Deleted Objects,DC=example,DC=com
…

# Comnisca
DEL:97f85a86-f326-4df1-b747-4bc9002b28c2, Deleted Objects, example.com
dn: CN=Comnisca\0ADEL:97f85a86-f326-4df1-b747-4bc9002b28c2,CN=Deleted Objects,
 DC=example,DC=com
distinguishedName: CN=Comnisca\0ADEL:97f85a86-f326-4df1-b747-4bc9002b28c2,CN=D
 eleted Objects,DC=example,DC=com
…
```

Only root may access the recycling bin, who’d have thought?

The privileges governing various access methods to the
recycle bin are documented in the section “Delegating Active
Directory Recycle Bin operations” of this document:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd392260%28v%3dws.10%29